# Drawing getbounds rectangle or rectangleF?

Tags: c#, graphic, drawrectangle, graphicspath

I have a `List` with `float` coordinates and I'm trying to draw a rectangle around a line previously drawn.

```
Graphics G = e.Graphics;    
Pen pen5 = new Pen(Color.DodgerBlue, 0.01f);
var rect2 =  new RectangleF();

GraphicsPath maliOkvir = new GraphicsPath();
maliOkvir.AddLine(((float)(odabraniSegment[0].startX)),
                   (float)(odabraniSegment[0].startY),
                   (float)(odabraniSegment[0].endX),
                   (float)(odabraniSegment[0].endY));

rect2 = maliOkvir.GetBounds();
G.DrawRectangle(pen5, rect2);
```

I'm getting an error on `rect2` part:

```
G.DrawRectangles(pen5, rect2);
```

> Cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.RectangleF' to 'System.Drawing.RectangleF[]'

How can I fix this? tried multiple variations of `Rectangle` and `RectangleF`, none works together.. the end result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: At first glance, it looks like whatever `e` is, has the method `DrawRectangles` in it - which alludes to the fact it might take an array of `RectangleF`s (`RectangleF[]`) - hence your error. Looking at the `Graphics` Class, it  has a `.DrawRectangle` (singular) method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx8yykw8(v=vs.110).aspx Are you sure you're using the right method?

Comment: `DrawRectangles` expects an array of rectangles, you probably want `DrawRectangle` (without the s on the end)

Comment: @DavidG you're right, my bad, it was a leftover from previous attempts to fix it.

Comment: So your issue is fixed now?

Comment: Nope, the same error remains.

Comment: Exactly the same error? That's not possible.

Comment: @DavidG Exactly the same. The `DrawRectangle` command doesn't want float values but my `rect2` can only be made to `RectangleF`, if i remove the F, new error comes up on the `GetBounds` command because it also needs `float` values.

Comment: Well like I said in my answer, you can also use option 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DrawRectangles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangles(v=vs.110).aspx) method expects an array of `Rectangle` or `RectangleF` objects but you are only passing in a single item. You should either:

1. Switch to use the singular version of the method, i.e. [`DrawRectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Pass in an array:

   ```
   G.DrawRectangles(pen5, new [] { rect2 });
   ```

Comment: or 3. Pass in the float values: `g.DrawRectangle(pen5, rect2.X, rect2.Y, rect2.Width, rect2.Height);`  :-)

Comment: Indeed @LarsTech, was tempted to add that one, but it's always a PITA to remember the parameter order.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `DrawRectangles()` method of `System.Drawing.Graphics`, which expects an array of `Rectangle`s.

Use the singular version: `DrawRectangle()`:

```
G.DrawRectangle(pen5, rect2.Left, rect2.Top, rect2.Width, rect2.Height); // Singular
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx) gives you (a lot) of information about the `Graphics` class.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A mistake on my part, it should have been DrawRectangle, I only need one, but I just need the functions to all take float values, so the thing can work :)

Comment: Glad to have helped @Romy! Easy mistake to make. Don't forget to mark as answer when you're done. Happy programming :)

Comment: Although the extra "s" was a mistake, the same problem still remains :/

Comment: *Exactly* the same error? That's not possible. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your solution?

Comment: Yea weird, but DavigG suggested sticking with the array way, and that worked. :)

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion of passing an array with only the `rect2` in it, like David suggested. Glad you got it working :)

Comment: Worth noting that you can pass in a `Rectangle`, but not a `RectangleF` (as is provided in the original question).  For `RectangleF`, you have to pass `X`, `Y`, `Width`, and `Height` as individual arguments to [this overload of Graphics.DrawRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-drawing-graphics-drawrectangle(system-drawing-pen-system-single-system-single-system-single-system-single))